# Vue.js Element UI - Howto remove file in custom upload template thumbnail

Tags: element-ui

I customized the Upload component as shown in the example **(https://element.eleme.io/#/es/component/upload#personalizar-el-template-thumbnail)** in the documentation, but when I click on the delete icon, it has no effect.

I checked the code of the component and I find that an event called remove should be emitted.

[image]

How should this action be implemented to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

add `this.$refs.uploader.handleRemove(file)` to `handleRemove` method.